# Neo4j Cypher Java Jersey Message body writer not found

Tags: java, neo4j, jersey

I'm new to neo4j and jersey.  I'm trying to follow the neo4j documentation for using the Cypher endpoints in Java with Jersey to do simple queries from a server [1], [2].  My code is below [4].  As well as my pom.xml [5].

I keep running in into an error that I have seen a lot on the boards about a missing message body writer [6].  Several of the solutions involve editing the rest server code and adding annotations.  I'm looking for a different solution as I plan to use a neo4j server as an out of the box graph database.  I've included my pom as many of the other answers suggest including specific packages to fix the problem.  I tried including those and saw so success.

Any ideas?

[1] http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.3/cypher-intro-applications.html

[2] http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-java-rest-client-example.html#_creating_a_node

[4] 
    String query = "MATCH (m:Movie) RETURN m";

```
String uri = host + "/db/data/transaction/commit";

String cypherStatements = "{\"statements\": [\"statement\":{"+query+"}]}";

WebResource resource = Client.create().resource((uri));

ClientResponse response = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .entity(cypherStatements)
    .post(ClientResponse.class);

System.out.println(String
    .format("PUT to [%s], status code [%d]", uri, response.getStatus()));
```

[5]

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Assemble the jar file including all it's dependencies. This is nescesary
                for DataCleaner to load them all collectively. -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <!--<repository>-->
        <!--<id>snapshot-repository.java.net</id>-->
        <!--<name>Java.net Snapshot Repository for Maven</name>-->
        <!--<url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>-->
        <!--<layout>default</layout>-->
    <!--</repository>-->
    <repository>
        <id>maven-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Maven 1 Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        <layout>legacy</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Include DataCleaner as a provided dependency -->
        <groupId>org.eobjects.datacleaner</groupId>
        <artifactId>DataCleaner-desktop-ui</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-RC3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[6]

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.String, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.String, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.String, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.String, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

Answer (score 0):

Oh so it looks like you are using the client, but not defining an endpoint right? In this case you need to register the message body writer/reader with the client, auto discovery works only with server side.

With Genson you can do it [this way](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/Extensions/#jax-rs-jersey--cie).

Comment: So I add ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig(GensonJsonConverter.class); and I'm getting a java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException

Comment: You should post the full stacktrace

Comment: Genson does not use the mail api, so something else must depend on it. If your app does work with emails then you need to add javax mail to your dependencies.

Comment: This is the full stacktrace.  I understand what is going on until it hits the jersey code where the email problem comes up.  My code is not attempting to send emails.

Comment: javax.mail.MessagingException
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper$3.run(ReflectionHelper.java:289)
 com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper$3.run(ReflectionHelper.java:279)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$AbstractLazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:697)

Comment: com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.toClassArray(ServiceFinder.java:549)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:345)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:338)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:162)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:343)

Comment: com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:119)
com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:192)
com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:188)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:188)
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:171)
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:683)

Comment: Hum I have no idea why this error happens :( I guess an easy fix would be to add the javax mail api/impl as dependencies.